# Learning comparisons

Tags: ranking

Suppose I want (the machine) to learn the ">" function, and my training set is a collection of pairs of numbers $(n_1, n_2)$ with the output `True` if $n_1 > n_2$ and `False` otherwise. Which method is the most likely to work (actually, my secret goal is a form of the Netflix challenge - I have a set of $n$-tuples of real and boolean values, and I want to rank them based on some training rank data).

This has surely been studied a lot...

Comment: You've stumbled on _[pair-wise learning-to-rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_to_rank#Pairwise_approach)_. Throw the concatenation of your two tuples (cf. _feature concatenation_) into a binary classifier (e.g., logistic regression). But this is not guaranteed to yield an unambiguous list since the classifier might decide A>B, B>C, yet C>A, so that's something for you to think about :)

Comment: @Emre Yes, I have since done exactly what you suggest, and it works pretty well (although reading the wikipedia article on logistic regression, there seems to be much murk about how many samples you need, etc...)

Answer (score 1):

The classical solution is to try a one-class SVM applied only to the elements ranked above the others - you can read some papers about it looking by SVM rank or SVM ranking that will show you why that works.