# Learning ranking

Tags: logistic-regression, ranking

This is a sort of a follow-up to [this newbie question:](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/18934/learning-comparisons)Suppose I want learn *ranking* (so, I have a bunch of data points, ranked $1, 2, 3, ...$ Now, one way is to use something like logistic regression with training data pairs of data points, and labels like $(a, b) \to \mathbf{TRUE}.$ The other way is to have single datapoints and labels the actual rank value (like $a\to 1, b\to 17, \dots.$) Both methods have obvious drawbacks: the first that there is a quadratic amount of somewhat redundant data, the second that the rank is somehow not really a real number, and the actual differences of the scoring function between adjacent ranks could be wildly variable. Is there any prevailing wisdom on this?

Comment: Why the downvote, dare I ask?

Comment: People are strange at that small communities, as opposite to MO, they downvote many questions which they do not find braindamaging enough :)

Comment: @AlexanderChervov I would have thought that there would be more people doing datascience than math these days ...

Comment: It might be, there is so much buzz about it nowdays , but they may use other communication ways... MO is much more active than many other like q-fin e.g. Any way you might try Cross-validated . There Douglas Zare  active https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:11981+[machine-learning] At least one smart guy from MO..